# `virsh start` crashes CentOS 7 host

Tags: kvm, libvirt, crash, virsh

This just began yesterday after the host system was shutdown and booted back up.

Upon running `virsh start [guest-name]`, it immediately dumps this output and forcibly reboots the host:

[image: crash screen 1]

[image: crash screen 2]

The only thing that sticks out to me there is the `Firmware bug` line near the top of the second picture.

I have run `yum update` and updated the BIOS, same result.  None of the guest configurations have changed.  As a test, I installed Rocky 8 on spare drive, installed libvirt, installed a guest OS and it ran perfectly fine, so I don't think it's hardware.

I'd rather not do a whole reinstall and reconfiguration.  How I trace and fix this?

Comment: Why not just backup your config and data files and start over with Rocky?  Or maybe upgrade to Centos 8, then use the migrate2rocky script to switch to Rocky.  Centos is dead (for over 2 years now), and Rocky Linux seems like the most viable replacement for it.     My guess is that the crash is due to a kernel bug (3.10.x is ancient) which isn't ever likely to be updated on Centos 7. Rocky has a much newer kernel (4.18 for Rocky 8, 5.14 for Rocky 9).   IIRC, Centos 8 uses 4.18 too so even that might be enough to solve your problem (temporarily at least, centos is dead)

Comment: @cas: yeah I suppose I should just install Rocky anyway, but it would be nice to know what caused this failure.